# how to keep this app nodejs running even when closing ssh?

Tags: node.js

hello I am total beginner when it comes to nodejs.
I was working on PHP code but found this app that will suit my needs for a project this is my first time to nodejs and managed to get this app working.  https://github.com/KiraLT/torrent-stream-server .
the command to get it running is torrent-stream-server serve
which works great but i have to keep it running and not touch for it to work any help with this please?
i have spent my whole night searching i found like forever and pm2 but i did not know how to use since serve command

Comment: what do you want exactly?? do you want how to run this project with pm2 ?

Comment: i want to keep it running an up with anyway possible not pm2 necessarily

Comment: You can do it with pm2 easily

Comment: can you help me please what command do i need to use ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. go to the folder path of project
2. npm i
3. npm install pm2@latest -g
4. pm2 start app_name if you want to run attached project to the question you can use this command: `pm2 start npm --name "app_name" -- start`
5. pm2 startup
6. pm2 save

**note** : `pm2 startup` can generate startup scripts and configure them in order to keep your process list intact across expected or unexpected machine restarts.

**note** : `pm2 save` to freeze a process list for automatic respawn

for managing application state is simple here are the commands :

```
pm2 ls
pm2 restart app_name
pm2 reload app_name
pm2 stop app_name
pm2 delete app_name
pm2 logs app_name
```

Comment: i tried getting the app path and this is what i get 
# which torrent-stream-server
/bin/torrent-stream-server
# cd /bin/torrent-stream-server
-bash: cd: /bin/torrent-stream-server: Not a directory

Comment: also even when doing pm2 start npm --name "app name" -- start it start but problem is running the app needs this command "app name" serve not just app name